# Problems with MySQLdb python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, mysql-python

When I try connect to `mysql` with user `"root"`, my application returns `"Access denied for user *"ODBC"@"localhost" (using password:NO)"*`. I dnt know why this appear.

Im using Tkinter like GUI, I tested only Connection's script, its Okay.

Code Connection

```
import MySQLdb

class Conexao():
    def __init__(self, host,user,passwd,db):
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.passwd = passwd
        self.db = db

    def getconnection(self):
        try:
            self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=self.host,
                                        user = self.user,
                                        passwd = self.passwd,
                                        db = self.db)
            print "Connected"
            return self.conn.cursor()
        except MySQLdb.Error,e:
            print " error "+ str(e[1])
            return e
```

Code App

```
from Tkinter import *

import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'C:\\Users\\felipe.cunha\\Documents\\project')

from conexao.conexao import Conexao


"""
b.execute("select * from setor")
>>> b.fetchall()
"""
class View(Frame):
        def __init__(self,master = None):
                Frame.__init__(self)
                self.master.title("teste")
                self.create_menu()
        def create_menu(self):#,width = self.width,height = self.height):
                host = "localhost"
                label_menu = Label(self.master,text = 'Login')
                label_menu.pack()

                entrada_menu_login = Entry(self.master)# user
                entrada_menu_senha = Entry(self.master, show = "*")# passwd                

                conn = Conexao(host,entrada_menu_login.get(),entrada_menu_senha.get(),"dsti")
                #conn = Conexao(host,"root","d04m10","dsti")


                btn_login = Button(self.master,text="Logar",command = conn.getConnection)#self.show_entry_fields)

                entrada_menu_login.pack()
                entrada_menu_senha.pack()
                btn_login.pack()


        def show_entry_fields(self):
                print(self.entrada_menu_login.get(), self.entrada_menu_senha.get())





app = View()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is your mysql db running on the standard port - 3306 ? Is the issue only occuring when using tkinter frontend along with your connection script?

Comment: Yes,3306. when I use tkinter front-end, always appear this error. I cant access my database with root, but i try to execute Connection's class, its works.

Comment: Can you try printing - `print(entrada_menu_senha.get())` ,just before creating the `Conexao` object and update us the result ?

Comment: Yes, I create the def show_entry_field and "printed" entrada_menu_login and entrada_menu_senha, they return same string.

Comment: Same string as in correct ones? And is this a typo when you copied the code to SO - `command = conn.getConnection` ?

Comment: yes, same. My input are login - "root" passwd - "d04m10", return same things

Comment: And the above is just a typo?

Comment: No, typo. I made teste. When i put this code conn = Conexao(host,"root","d04m10","dsti") , the connection is work.

Comment: Maybe what is being returned by `entrada_menu_senha.get()` is not be a string, could you try checking the `print(type(entrada_menu_senha.get()))`

Comment: I tried. I made def show_entry_fields(self):
          print(type(self.entrada_menu_login.get()), type(self.entrada_menu_senha.get())) and it returned (<type 'str'>, <type 'str'>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Bryan said, that may be the issue with your code, instead of making the button call conn.getConnection() directly, try an approach, where you save the entry variables into 'self' and then when the button is invoked, you create the connection at that time.

The code would look something like -

```
class View(Frame):
        def __init__(self,master = None):
                Frame.__init__(self)
                self.master.title("teste")
                self.create_menu()
        def create_menu(self):#,width = self.width,height = self.height):
                host = "localhost"
                label_menu = Label(self.master,text = 'Login')
                label_menu.pack()

                self.entrada_menu_login = Entry(self.master)# user
                self.entrada_menu_senha = Entry(self.master, show = "*")# passwd


                btn_login = Button(self.master,text="Logar",command = self.buttonListener) #self.show_entry_fields

                entrada_menu_login.pack()
                entrada_menu_senha.pack()
                btn_login.pack()

        def buttonListener(self):
            conn = Conexao(host,self.entrada_menu_login.get(),self.entrada_menu_senha.get(),"dsti")                                
            #conn = Conexao(host,"root","d04m10","dsti")
            dbcursor = conn.getConnection()
            #Do the rest of the logic you want to do.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating the connection when your GUI starts up, before the user has the ability to type in a username or password. Both `entrada_menu_login` and `entrada_menu_senha` are blank at the time you create the connection.

The solution is to not create the connection until after the user has clicked the button.

Comment: Ok. How i make form correct to user introduce login and passwd 
? Why appear "ODBC" ?